# How to print two lines next to each other using awk or sed?

Tags: linux, shell, scripting

I know i can use `awk 'NR==10' < 1.txt` to print 10th line of text file.

How do i format it like ::

10th line :: 14th line

11th line :: 15th line

16th line :: 18th line

Iam comfortable with both ways either awk or sed. Please Help ?

Comment: What is logic behind 10, 11 and 16 ?

Comment: A good question will have a small set of sample data, expected output from that input, current code/output/error msgs and your thoughts about why things aren't working. Also, use 4 spaces at the front of each line of code/data/error msgs OR highlight a block of text and use the `{}` format tool at the top left of the edit box to format as code/data/output. Please read , http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask , http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and maybe the http://stackoverflow.com/tour . Good luck.

Comment: there is no logic @anubhava Actually problem was to print line 5,6,7,8 and lines 10,11,12,13 in front of them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `awk` as this:

```
awk 'NR ~ /^1[016]$/{a[NR]=$0} NR==14||NR==15{print a[NR-4] " : " $0} 
     NR==18{print a[NR-2] " : " $0}' file

Line 10 : Line 14
Line 11 : Line 15
Line 16 : Line 18
```

Where file is this:

```
cat file

Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
Line 4
Line 5
Line 6
Line 7
Line 8
Line 9
Line 10
Line 11
Line 12
Line 13
Line 14
Line 15
Line 16
Line 17
Line 18
Line 19
Line 20
```

Comment: It doesn't solve my problem. and more-over there are issues with formatting.